# Testing on a second iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have developed my first full fledged iPhone app, and tested it on my phone.  I would like to have it tested by one of the contributing graphic artists on their iPhone.  They live in another state so I do not have access to their device.  I added their Device ID to the apple portal.

A couple of questions:
I do not see the device show in Xcode when I hit refresh.  Should I be seeing it?
Which executable file(s) do I send to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [testflight](https://testflightapp.com). It makes distributing apps very easy. Since you have already included the designers device ID, all you have to do is:

- Sign up to test flight
- invite the designer and tell him to register and add his device info
- go to apple developer portal - provisioning - distribution and create a new distribution profile (don't forget to add the designers device when creating the profile), download and open the certificate (which will be shown in Xcode's Window>Organizer) - make sure that the correct certificates are selected in your build settings.
- make sure that iOS device is selected ( and not the simulator) now in Xcode go to Product>Archive, when the archive is shown click distribute>adhoc distribution
- this will create an IPA file.
- upload this to test flight and follow the instructions to select the designer from your team.

Answer (score 1):

Use TestFlight. It's free, takes 5 mins to install their API, and gives step by step instructions on how to push your app to any tester over the air.

Answer (score 1):

Add their device id to your developer account, Update your adhoc profile (which you are using for running your app on device) attach their device with this profile. Now again sign your build with updated profile and give this APP file and provisioning profile to others or upload it on TestFlight.